# Prove Tautology Using Laws of Equivalency

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Hi guys i need your help to prove that $P \wedge Q$ is equivalent to $P \wedge (P\rightarrow Q)$. So basically I want to convert $P \wedge Q$ to $P \wedge (P\rightarrow Q)$.

$P \wedge Q\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$                  Left hand side of the equivalence

$(P \wedge Q) \vee (P \wedge Q)\qquad$      Distributive laws

*dead end for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert $P \wedge (P \rightarrow Q)$ to $P \wedge (\neg P \vee Q)$, then convert it to $(P \wedge \neg P) \vee (P \wedge Q)$, you get $\bot \vee (P \wedge Q)$, which is equivalent to $P \wedge Q$.

Comment: i thought about that but the problem is P ^ Q is the one i need to convert and see its process

Comment: @GeromeTahud Reverse these steps.

Comment: Okay thanks. I got it now